# "Module Not Found error" when dynamically import images from directory with create-react-app and react-router-dom

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, dynamic-import

I am using Create-React-App with react-router-dom and looking to use dynamic import to load images from different directory.

Something like this

```
// visit the url will show images in projectName folder
pseudo.com/category/projectName
```

I've read the document of Webpack, it said the import() must have some information about the module is located.So I passed the last level of directory name rather than the whole directory as props to component.

This is my current way of importing(which does not work)

```
// ImageGallery.js
function ImageGallery({ galleryDirectory }) {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadImages = async () => {
      try {
        const imageContext = await import(
          `./img/portfolio/${galleryDirectory}`
        );
        const imagePaths = imageContext.keys();
        const imageComponents = await Promise.all(
          imagePaths.map(async (path) => {
            const module = await import(
              `./img/portfolio/${galleryDirectory}/${path.slice(2)}`
            );
            const imageSrc = module.default;
            return <img keys={path} src={imageSrc} alt={path} />;
          })
        );
        setImages(imageComponents);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("error loading images:", error);
      }
    };
    loadImages();
  }, [galleryDirectory]);
  return <>{images}</>;
}

export default ImageGallery;
```

The file which contains data of each project

```
// projectData.js
export const projectData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category: "graphic",
    name: "graphic_project_1",
    portfolioCover: require("../img/portfolio/cover/graphic1_cover.jpg"),
    workCover: require("../img/portfolio/cover/graphic1_cover.jpg"),
    galleryDirectory: "graphic1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category: "website",
    name: "website_project_1",
    portfolioCover: require("../img/portfolio/cover/web1_cover.jpg"),
    workCover: require("../img/portfolio/cover/web1_cover.jpg"),
    galleryDirectory: "web1"
  }
];
```

The folder structure is

```
public/
src/
  api/
    projectData.js
  img/
    portfolio/
      graphic1/
        graphic_1.jpg
        graphic_2.jpg
        ...
      web1/
        web_1.png
        web_2.jpg
        ...
  App.js
  ImageGallery.js
  SingleProject.js
  index.js
```

The error message
[module not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJOLQ.png)

Here's the
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-import-image-from-directory-vf6wts?file=/src/api/imgData.js)